# Is there a way to combine the following conditions in a shorter way?

Tags: python, list

The following code works but I wonder if there's a way to combine the following conditions in a shorter way?

```py
xlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
xlist[:] = [x for x in xlist if ('a' not in x) & ('b' not in x)]
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```py
xlist[:] = [x for x in xlist if ['a', 'b'] not in x]
```

Comment: As an aside, `if ('a' not in x) & ('b' not in x)` should be `if ('a' not in x) and ('b' not in x)`

Comment: If the list always contains single characters: `... if x not in 'ab'`.

Comment: if the elements ar ehashable, then you can do `[x for x in xlist if set(x).isdisjoint(excluded_set)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
xlist[:] = [x for x in xlist if all(i not in x for i in ['a', 'b'])]
```

This makes little difference if you're only looking to exclude a list of two things - but if you had a much longer list of strings you wanted to exclude, this could be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if the element in the xlist is like above,then:

`[x for x in xlist if x not in 'ab']`